# Sign in to slack app through browser

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, chrome

I am a linux newbie and currently using Elementary OS (which I believe is basically Ubuntu 18.04 LTS). I have installed chromium, firefox and slack using snap store. Now, when I try to log in to slack through any of the browsers, the slack app does not open. I can see the app popping up in the task bar but it never launches. Now, my question is - "Is there anyway that I can debug the whole process to find out where it's causing the problem? And if anyone can guess what the problem is exactly, can you please explain what is causing the issue? Is it related to snap installation?"

Comment: Starting the Slack application from the command line might show you some useful error messages...

Comment: Slack starts fine, however when the browser creates a new instance of slack when I try to open it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a workaround.  I removed the snapcraft's FireFox installation and installed from the good old package manager. Used that as a default browser and it solved the issue. I believe I missed out some configuration for the snap one. I would really like to know what was the real reason behind it.